# Zend / ZF2 / TableGateway update() how to process this "hits = hits + 1"

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to write a sql like this:

```
"Update tablename SET hits = hits + 1 WHERE id = $id"
```

In zf2, we used TableGateway, I write the code:

```
$this->tablenametableGateway->update(array(
  'hits' => new Expression('hits + 1')),array(
        'id' => $id)
  );
```

But the result is something wrong, example: 
first hits equal 1 , after refresh the page , hits equal 3, hits increase 2 every times, not increase 1.

I don't know how to sovle this problem, need you help, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your hitcounter isn't being called twice on each request? It might help to include details of where you're actually calling the code in your application.

Comment: Thanks for Crisp's answer! I'm sure hitcounter is not beging called twice on each request! I write the code "echo 'hitcounter';" before TableGateway->update(...), and then print once "hitcounter" in the application page!

Answer (score -7):

I solved the problem. I installed Chrome extension "Web Server Notifier", This extension will cause the chrome to access the 2 times the current page, very fast!  After closed the extension,my code run well!

Comment: And what does this have to do with the question?